# What Component? A property of $SOMEOUTLET was modified inside the didInsertElement hook

Tags: ember.js

I have an app with a number of components on the page. I'd really like to know what component a given deprecation is related to.  Is there a way to map an outlet to a component?

In other words if I get:

> A property of <frontend@view:-outlet::ember673> was modified inside
>   the didInsertElement hook. You should never change properties on
>   components, services or models during didInsertElement because it
>   causes significant performance degradation.

What component is being used for ember673 ?

Comment: I guess it's an enternal component ID emberjs uses to identify the component. You could look into Ember console of your browser to find out more, or run jQuery selector `find('.ember673')` or `('#ember673')` to locate the element within your DOM.

Comment: Ember views/components map to ids.  They don't ever map to classes, which makes sense.  I assume this is how actions work in Ember.  For the particular case above there was not a DOM element with an id of ember673. I ended up finding out what component had the problem, by commenting out code =0/

Comment: @hewsonism, could you please explain what you did? I am almost giving up on this one.

Comment: I had to do a binary search of commenting code out until I found the component at fault